# Using a variable from a separate view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get input from a text field and display that on a label in a separate view controller.

I am trying to get the partyID from PartyViewController:

```
class PartyViewController: UIViewController {

    // CALLS LOGIN VC
    var LoginViewController: LoginViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var partyID: UITextField!
```

Into my second view controller:

```
class GuestPartyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var PartyViewController.partyID:
        UILabel!
```

This gives me several errors.. 
Class 'GuestPartyViewController' has no initializers

Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
Expected declaration 
Type annotation missing in pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can access variable like this:

```
class PartyViewController: UIViewController {

var partyID: Type = Value

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
}
```

Another controller

```
var GuestPartyViewController: PartyViewController = PartyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
var getPartyId = GuestPartyViewController.partyID
```